# mcrypt перестал работать

Tags: php, mcrypt

на бесплатном хосте был скрипт такого содержания:

```
<?php
function String2Hex($string){
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
return $hex;
```

}

```
function Hex2String($hex){
$string='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
    $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
}
return $string;
}

function PKCS5AddPadding($input) {
    $pad = strlen($input) % 16;
    for ($i = $pad; $i < 16; $i++) {
        $input .= chr(16 - $pad);
    }
    return $input;
}
function PKCS5RemovePadding($input) {
    return rtrim($input, substr($input, strlen($input) - 1, 1));
}

function kn_dec($ciph,$key) {
$cipherText = base64_decode($ciph);
$plainText = PKCS5RemovePadding(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key, $cipherText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));    
return $plainText;
}

function kn_enc($plai,$key) {
$plainText = $plai;
$cipherText = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, PKCS5AddPadding($plainText), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);  
 $cipherText = base64_encode($cipherText);

 return $cipherText;
}




if (isset($_POST['te'])) {

 die(String2Hex(kn_enc($_POST['te'],'!(*@&#^$%!&%^&*@')));

} else if (isset($_POST['td'])) {
die(kn_dec(Hex2String($_POST['td']),'!(*@&#^$%!&%^&*@'));
}
```

Его предназначение – шифровать и расшифровывать текст. Скрипт нормально работал, но сегодня начал выдавать пустой ответ.

Перенёс скрипт на свой сервер, в логах ничего нет. Я думаю, это связано с версиями mCrypt, может, кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К слову, про `mcrypt()`:
https://dotdev.co/upcoming-changes-in-php-7-1-76ebea53b820#.mmbyk76xk

Короткое содержание:

В связи с тем, что библиотека не поддерживается и содержит множество багов, решено, что с версии PHP 7.1 она DEPRECATED, и будет убрана в последующих версиях. Так что, если планируете переходить на новые версии языка - это еще одна из вещей, которые надо проверить на обратную совместимость с вашим проектом.